# Excel separate cell value

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

[image: Please click me for image example]

How do I split the text so each option goes to the appropriate option cell(A,B,C.D,E).

Please note that the option text length may vary as well and some option might be missing. For example option `B` might be missing, leaving the option in the cell as `ACDE`, how can I get it to skip the empty option and go to the next.

Comment: So you want to match the first letter in each string with the column letter? Could you edit your picture please to remove the extraneous text? Have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: You have to find some common logic that can be define to separate all options in your full string of options. For example each option is starting with A,B,C,D or E followed by a dot, or each option is starting with  a character | etc, this logic can then be implemented in a formula to separate your text string.

Comment: As an array formula this will split your example options by the `|` bar:  `Public Function SplitOptions(Target As Range) As Variant: SplitOptions = Split(Target, "|"): End Function`

Comment: You might consider forcing the Text Import feature.

Answer (score 0):

I would tend to use 2 cells working together.

Typically, assuming that the string to parse is in C5, your cell first cell (D5 in my example) could contain:

```
=MID(C5,FIND("|",C5)+1,LEN(C5))
```

This cell would contain the remaining string to parse.

Your second cell could contain:

```
=LEFT(C5,LEN(C5)-LEN(D5)-1)
```

It would use the remaining string to parse as determined above and take the left part of it until the next delimiter.

If you do so, the last column will not work, so you will have to take care about manually.