# Excel Separate Pipe Delimited String into separate columns - where value starts with A, B, C but values in string are not cronological

Tags: excel

I have an excel sheet, which has values from a database.  One cell has responses from a multiple choice question which is pipe delimited.  eg a user could ask what colour cars have you had?  With options such as:

```
A. Black
B. White
C. Red
D. Yellow
```

So a user can respond with A, C and D.  these values are stored in one cell as "A. Black|C. Red|D. Yellow"  I want to separate each of these values in a A column, B column, C column and D column.

I tried using the Text to Column feature but this does know that the A column should only contain As.

I thin I need to add a formula to each column which looks for the "A.", "B.", "C." or "D." and then finds the next available pipe character.  I think I need a substring of some sort maybe.  Something like this maybe:

```
=LEFT(C2,LEN(C2)-FIND("A.",C2))
```

But I don't know how to find the next occurrence of the pipe symbol - any ideas?  Is there a nextIndexOf function in excel maybe?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show what the starting cell looks like along with the expected output? Sometimes a photo is better, and I think this is one of those cases :)

Comment: Is this the same [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53375985/excel-separate-cell-value) asked by @Andrew.O?  Not sure, but very similar....

Answer (score 0):

I think this would require either VBA or Power Query, because you are talking about having to analyze the data to determine what column it goes into. It's actually very easy to do in Power Query, but if you've never even heard of Power Query (it's built into Excel 2016+ and is a free add-in for 2013) then this solution is probably out of scope without an extensive explanation of what Power Query is.

That being said, for anyone interested, I took this dummy set of data, and converted it into an output table with Power Query which I believe is what was being asked in the question.

[image]

[image]

This is the code for the Query. A quick summary is we split it by the pipe delimiters and index it. Then the main trick is using the Group function combined with the Transpose function to get the split columns into an unpivoted data set. After expanding back out from the Group we can then split out the "ABCD" section from the answer, and pivot off that to get the ABCD columns aligned with the original entries.

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(Source, "Column1", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter("|", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"Column1.1", "Column1.2", "Column1.3", "Column1.4"}),
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Split Column by Delimiter", "Index", 1, 1),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Added Index", {"Index"}, {{"Rows", each Table.Transpose(Table.RemoveColumns(_, {"Index"})), type table}}),
    #"Expanded Rows" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Rows", {"Column1"}, {"Rows.Column1"}),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Expanded Rows", each ([Rows.Column1] <> null)),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter1" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Filtered Rows", "Rows.Column1", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(". ", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"Selection", "Answer"}),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Split Column by Delimiter1", List.Distinct(#"Split Column by Delimiter1"[Selection]), "Selection", "Answer")
in
    #"Pivoted Column"
```